# Unity - 2D Top-Down player rotates strangely to face the mouse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a top-down shooter in Unity, and did the "movement" and "look at mouse" scripts, and the player rotates normally to face the mouse, but then I applied a `Vector2.Lerp` to smooth the rotation a bit and now when the player's Z rotation (the game is being played on the xy axis) reaches 0, the player makes a 360 degree turn to the other side of the 0 degree mark, and continues tracking the mouse until the mouse goes below the 0 degree mark again so the player does the turn again.

I really don't know why this is happening. Here's the player rotation code:

```
void FixedUpdate(){
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        
        
        Vector2 lookDir = mousePos - rb.position;
        float currentAngle = rb.rotation;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(lookDir.y, lookDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
        float smoothedAngle = Mathf.Lerp(currentAngle, angle, rotationTime);
        if(canAim==true){
        rb.rotation = smoothedAngle;

        }
        
    }
```

The first line is for movement and the following is for rotation. I really want that smooth rotation but can't find out how to do it without that strange rotation appearing!

[Here is a GIF I made, it shows exactly what the problem is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlFc9.gif).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of working only with absolute angles, you should calculate the difference in angle between the current angle and the destination angle:

```
void FixedUpdate(){
    rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);


    Vector2 lookDir = mousePos - rb.position;
    float currentAngle = rb.rotation;
    float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(lookDir.y, lookDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
    float angleDiff = targetAngle - currentAngle;
```

Then for any angles greater than or equal to `180`, change them to their negative angle equivalent, because it's the closer direction:

```
    angleDiff = Mathf.Repeat(angleDiff + 180f, 360f) - 180f;
```

Then, rotate towards that angle:

```
    targetAngle = currentAngle + angleDiff;
    float smoothedAngle = Mathf.Lerp(currentAngle, targetAngle, rotationTime);
    if(canAim==true){
    rb.rotation = smoothedAngle;

    }

}
```

Comment: Oh nice! I'll try that tomorrow and see if it works, it seems it would. Thank you!